# Save Form data in database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to get the selected radio button value to from html to server side so that i can save them in the data base i have done similar in php not sure how to do that in asp.net/ C#

```
<form runat="server" id='attendence_form' >
<table id="attendence_div" width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="0">
    <tr align="left" style="background-color:#004080;color:White;">
        <td>Student Name</td>                        
        <td>Present</td>            
        <td>Absent</td>       
        <td>Leave</td>                    
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ANITHA S</td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Present0" value="Present"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Present0" value="Absent"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Present0" value="Leave"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ANITHA T C</td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Present1" value="Present"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Present1" value="Absent"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Present1" value="Leave"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>BINDU K V</td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Present2" value="Present"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Present2" value="Absent"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Present2" value="Leave"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Hear is the php code this recives the html form values form the user side via ajax and insert i want the same in asp.net

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // ** insert data in to data base ** //
    $sql = "INSERT INTO attendance_master (AttendanceDate) VALUES ";
    // **hear the data or is calculated using student as a string the number of student names are passed the same number of data is inserted in to data base ** //
    foreach($_GET['student']  as $i=>$student) {

        // ** so the data is inserted in to data base   ** //
        $sql .= sprintf("%s ('%s')"
        , ($i==0 ? '' : ',')  
        // **  data from Ajax   ** //       
        , mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_GET['present'][$i]))

        );
    }
    // ** on success full function   ** //
    if ($conn->query($sql)) {
        // **can do any thing to recognise if the data is inserted if this gives the out put then the data is shorly inserted in to data base  ** //
    }
```

Comment: In asp.net you use asp:RadioButton instead. @AmitKumarGhosh the OP doesn't have any wrong, but he just don't know how to use radio button in asp.net.

Comment: @User2012384 your suggestion is correct, i will do it. however what i need is: The code which i have mentioned above is in PHP. however i need the code in asp. The code which i am talking about is:  `foreach($_GET['student']  as $i=>$student) {
        // ** so the data is inserted in to data base   ** //
        $sql .= sprintf("%s ('%s')"
        , ($i==0 ? '' : ',')  
        // **  data from Ajax   ** //
        , mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_GET['present'][$i]))
        );`

Comment: @User2012384 also the radio buttons are generated dynamically. Each Radio group has 3 radio buttons (Present, absent and leave). When a user choose one radio button from the radio group against 10 users, i want this code to capture that selected radio button information and save it in MySQL DB

Comment: Then try using "RadioButtonList" instead. then get the value by RadioButtonList.SelectedItem.Value then you create insert statement as normal.

Comment: sure vl try that and let u know but how to get the vlue to save in db

Comment: @User2012384 i have a question `htmlStr += "<tr><td><input type='text' readonly='readonly' value='" + reg + "'/></td><td><input type='text' readonly='readonly' value='" + Name + "'/></td> <asp:RadioButtonList ID='rblist" + numberofrow + "' runat='server'><th><asp:ListItem Text ='Present' Value='Present' /></th><th><asp:ListItem Text ='Absent' Value='Absent' /></th><th><asp:ListItem Text ='Leave' Value='Leave' /></th></asp:RadioButtonList></tr>";`

Comment: @User2012384 is the above way to create a radio button from server side is correct for radio button list

Comment: Do not generate html like this. use RadioButtonList, then assign datasource to radio button list instead

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97938/discussion-between-shaik-and-user2012384).

Comment: i need ur help iam very weak in this can u help me out

Answer (score 0):

If it is a webforms project you should use

```
<asp:RadioButton id="someId" runat="server">
```

Update:

To handle when the radiobutton is clicked you need to handle the CheckedChanged event.

```
someId.CheckedChanged += event_CheckedChanged;

private void event_CheckedChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    ... do stuff...
}
```

Comment: vl do that but the radio buttons are generated dynamically. Each Radio group has 3 radio buttons (Present, absent and leave). When a user choose one radio button from the radio group against 10 users, i want this code to capture that selected radio button information and save it in MySQL DB

Comment: Then you handle when the button is clicked. I just added an update to the answer to show how you do that,

Answer (score 0):

you can try using `<asp: RadioButton id="" runat="server" >` .

In the  server side you can check the "Checked" property like this

```
if(radioBtn.Checked==true) {}
```